# How to pronunce "eng"

Tags: pronunciation

How to pronunce chinese "eng" ?

Is the "en" *part* of chinese "eng" like the english word "end" or is it like the english part "un" in "trunk" ?

Comment: Whether two sounds are heard similar really depends on the mother tongue of the listener.

Comment: And there is not "en" part in "eng" in pinyin. Just like there is no "heir" part in "their" in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is no, Mandarin *-en* is not part of *-eng*, just like English "sin" is not part of "sing".

Even though "ng" is written with two letters in both Mandarin and English, there is only one sound: [ŋ]. That's the sound at the end of "sing" in English. Pinyin *-n* is close to the sound at the end of "sin" in English.

I suggest that you play around with these words in English a bit until you realise that "ng" is actually *one* sound, even if it's written with two letters. The situation is analogous to *-n* and *-ng* in Mandarin.

The vowel is the central vowel [ə] in both cases, which is the most common sound in human speech. It's the same as "a" or "the" in English (although it can vary by English dialect, of course).

Comment: Again, thank you for your kind help